# TypeScript determine if variable of type A or B

Tags: typescript

Let's assume I have the following types:

```
type A = "foo" | "bar"
type B = "abc" | "def"

let x: A | B = "foo"
```

Right now, as far as I understand, x is of type A | B,

but actually, it has been assigned to be only of type A, right?

How can I find out that x uses an allowed value of type A **without** using code like

```
if(x === "foo" || x === "bar") {
    console.log("x is of type A")
}
```

Comment: You don't want to use an if condition?

Comment: At runtime, javascript knows nothing about ts types. your code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Because TypeScript is a [static type-checker](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#static-type-checking), it only operates at compile time. And because you've informed the compiler that `x` is of type `A | B`, then you also need to inform the compiler that (if a certain condition is true), then `x` can only be of type `A`. Therefore, the direct answer to your question is "it's not possible to narrow a type without using a conditional check of some sort".

A good reference for further exploration is the handbook section on type [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

Answer (score 0):

TS already knows

```
type A = '1';
type B = 2;

const x: A | B = '1';

x.repeat(2); // No error
```

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is you can't. TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript and types (at least types like that) do not exist in JavaScript. That means all the types you define are gone at runtime and you have no way of doing a runtime check to determine of which type a variable is.

There are exceptions to this. For example you can determine at runtime if a variable is a `string` or `number` using the `typeof` keyword:

```
const x: string | number = 'foo';
if (typeof x === 'string') {
  // do something
}
```

Another exception are classes. You can check if a variable is an instance of a specific class using the `instanceof` keyword:

```
class A { }
class B { }

const x: A | B = new A();

if (x instanceof A) {
  // do something
}
```

These things will work as expected and typescript also understands these keywords and will narrow types correctly.

For a situation like yours where the types you are using are typescript types that will be omitted at runtime, you really have to compare the values because the types are simply not available at runtime.

Comment: But code snipped attached to question can be evaluated at compile time (we have concrete string given to variable), so in this case TypeScript is able to determine correct type.

Comment: Yes absolutely and that's the correct way to do it. But OP explicitly asked for a way without directly comparing values.